# Add a Calendar to a SharePoint Site with STSADM

Tags: sharepoint-2007, sharepoint

Is it possible to add a calendar (events list) to a SharePoint site via STSADM?  I am working out a deployment script to help setup some test data, and I cannot seem to find any way to do this.  I hope that I am missing something obvious.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a list is not a built-in command for STSADM. You can get [3rd party STSADM extensions](http://stsadm.blogspot.com/2008/07/add-list.html) that will add this functionality.

Comment: Excellent.  Exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!